# Deleting data from a custom table in WordPress

Tags: query, customization

I am trying to delete records from my custom table but it does not delete anything.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_paypal" );

// some code to display here...

?>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <td><input type="submit"  name="delete" value="Delete"  /></td>
</form>
<?php
$myid= $retrieved_data->id;

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
        //global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->query(
              'DELETE  FROM $wpdb->paypal
               WHERE id = "'.$myid.'"
              '
        );

    }
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `$wpdb->prefix` insted of `$wpdb` in Delete query.

Example:

```
 $wpdb->query(
              'DELETE  FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'paypal
               WHERE id = "'.$myid.'"'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late... but the main issue in your question is that you are using single quotes (') in your statement:

```
$wpdb->query(
      'DELETE  FROM $wpdb->paypal
       WHERE id = "'.$myid.'"
      '
);
```

This means that `$wpdb->paypal` is not producing the result you are expecting. First, you assume this displays the "paypal" table name. But it doesn't.

If `$myid` has a value of `4`, your PHP code will produce this SQL statement :

```
DELETE FROM $wpdb->paypal WHERE id = 4
```

... instead of being:

```
DELETE FROM wp_paypal WHERE id = 4
```

To fix the issue, you must:

1. Change your single quotes to double quotes. ([Read why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/771496))
2. Add the table prefix in front of the table name.

Like this:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'paypal';
$wpdb->query( "DELETE  FROM {$table_name} WHERE id = '{$myid}'" );
```

Also, make sure [you sanitize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) the `$myid` variable because if I submit the value `0 OR 1=1`, this will produce this SQL statement:

```
DELETE FROM wp_paypal WHERE id = 0 OR 1=1
```

... and will delete every row in the table